# swagger.json endpoint throwing "404 Not Found" on WAS Server

Tags: websphere, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0, was

I am using Jersey 2.x and integrated Swagger into my application.
API Doc for Swagger Integration with Jersey   : [Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

1. **Running on Local Machine + Tomcat :**

   Swagger Endpoint running fine on my local machine if deployed on Tomcat. Please have a look on the screenshot below:
   [image]
2. **Running on WebSphere (WAS):**

   If I deploy the same war file on WAS, I am getting `404 Not Found` error for GET swagger.json endpoint. 
   However other CRUD operation APIs are working perfectly fine. I also able to see LOG statement printed in Bootstrap class which means swagger intilized but endpoint is not working as expected.
   [image]

Below is my Bootstrap class which I have initialized in web.xml

```
public class Bootstrap extends HttpServlet {
    private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Bootstrap.class);
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        System.out.println("Inside Bootstrap........");
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setTitle("Rest APIs Documentation");          
        beanConfig.setContact("you@your-company.com");
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        //beanConfig.setHost("localhost:9060");
        //beanConfig.setBasePath("/mdm-swagger/api");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.api.rs");
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        LOGGER.info("Inside Bootstrap finish........");
    }
}
```

I have commented host and basepath as I want to use swagger for documentation purpose not like any client.
Could you please suggest possible solution why I am getting 404 Not Found error?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have Jersey servlet mapped to `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>` in `web.xml`? Dobule check the SystemOut.log if you dont have any other exceptions during startup of your application.

Comment: yes. I have mapped it. Its working on tomcat but not endpoint not working on websphere( was). I could also see reflection log as well "Reflections took 38 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 8 keys and 15 values"

Comment: The File not found suggests that `/api/` path is not visible. So my guess is that servlet that should handle it is somehow not correctly initialized. Which WAS version are you using? Did you try to set PARENT_LAST classloader on your web module?

Comment: @Gas I am using `WebSphere Platform 9.0.0.0`. Regarding `/api/` path not visible, I am able to access `/api/login` and other resources. only `/api/swagger.json` not working. Also as suggested, tried to set PARENT_LAST, but no luck.

Comment: Did you check your server logs (particularly SystemOut.log) for errors or exceptions during application startup? If you have the context root correct, a 404 often means that the app's not there because it failed to start correctly.

Comment: It is really hard to tell. You would have to add full web.xml and SystemOut.log from clean restart. Also I'd strongly recommend updating to one of the latest fixes like 0.8.